Extract the review ratings from i-herb webpage using python
I am facing a problem in trying to extract the ratings in the following webpage.
https://gr.iherb.com/r/panoxyl-acne-foaming-wash-10-benzoyl-peroxide-maximum-strength-5-5-oz-156-g/103844
When I try to inspect the page, I see that there is no rating (e.g. 5 stars out of 5), instead it shows each star separately and when a star is yellow, it has a fill = #FAC627
Can you help me to extract the total rating of each review and not the stars separately?
ratings
My code is the following:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy


iherb = []

w, h = 10, 30
array_2d = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

for i in range(0,30):
    array_2d[i][0] = 0
    link = f'https://gr.iherb.com/r/panoxyl-acne-foaming-wash-10-benzoyl-peroxide-maximum-strength-5-5-oz-156-g/103844?sort=6&isshowtranslated=true&p={i}'

    headers = {
            'authority' : 'gr.iherb.com',
            'method' : 'GET',
            'path' : '/r/panoxyl-acne-foaming-wash-10-benzoyl-peroxide-maximum-strength-5-5-oz-156-g/103844',
            'scheme' : 'https',
            'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
            'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
            'Accept-Language' : 'el-GR,el;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5,tr;q=0.4',
            'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0',
            'Cookie' : 'ih-preference=store=0&country=GR&language=en-US&currency=EUR; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1709123509064r0.07748378471782247; notice_behavior=implied,eu; ih-cc-pref=eyJmdW5jdGlvbmFsIjowLCJhbmFseXRpY3MiOjB9; transactionIds=undefined; dscid=4d7b59b1-827f-4bdb-95a5-264b8176a8d2; ih-had-rw=1; persistent-ab-testing={"shopByCategory":{"experimentKey":"personalized-hp"}}; notice_preferences=3:; notice_gdpr_prefs=0,1,2,3:; cmapi_gtm_bl=; cmapi_cookie_privacy=permit 1,2,3,4; _gcl_au=1.1.386376902.1709123511; _scid=aed9a9eb-0ec4-48e6-84c6-4d16affd7e56; IR_gbd=iherb.com; _fbp=fb.1.1709123511903.408088675; FPID=FPID2.2.1gG73Lj35xxt5BHEG7g2sci3sUPSnpmXByELjZXDe5M%3D.1709123512; FPAU=1.1.386376902.1709123511; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=qSDdxSVXIseeurne9wtLpc0TT42; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU1qQXhZV1k1TXpJdE5XVTNNeTAwWWpCbUxXSXhObUV0TjJKa016SmpPREF3WVRJMA; pxcts=64d3dbc4-d635-11ee-ae8c-be60a279a264; _pxvid=62ca997f-d635-11ee-a8d1-56ccaa69a88f; sd_client_id=57c3628b-424d-497d-bb16-638defc0caf8; __pxvid=65231c22-d635-11ee-8ec4-0242ac120003; FPGCLAW=GCL.1709124255.CjwKCAiA0PuuBhBsEiwAS7fsNWA1tC3fv_4WVTETUPyE8PNKjzTMMcs-6EfRgElnikHNyvd4fUajVBoC7g4QAvD_BwE; FPGCLDC=GCL.1709124255.CjwKCAiA0PuuBhBsEiwAS7fsNWA1tC3fv_4WVTETUPyE8PNKjzTMMcs-6EfRgElnikHNyvd4fUajVBoC7g4QAvD_BwE; _gcl_aw=GCL.1709124255.CjwKCAiA0PuuBhBsEiwAS7fsNWA1tC3fv_4WVTETUPyE8PNKjzTMMcs-6EfRgElnikHNyvd4fUajVBoC7g4QAvD_BwE; _gcl_dc=GCL.1709124255.CjwKCAiA0PuuBhBsEiwAS7fsNWA1tC3fv_4WVTETUPyE8PNKjzTMMcs-6EfRgElnikHNyvd4fUajVBoC7g4QAvD_BwE; _gac_UA-229961-54=1.1709124255.CjwKCAiA0PuuBhBsEiwAS7fsNWA1tC3fv_4WVTETUPyE8PNKjzTMMcs-6EfRgElnikHNyvd4fUajVBoC7g4QAvD_BwE; ih-experiment=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; FPLC=8Jc1bL3J7jW37tG%2FC1z5RyZXKB%2F7M%2FJWOI2IEROExWFBd8%2FrG50a5kHr7rYsXUO0DrwgT8DaAJu5NrzjJ%2F%2BOr6mPxY6sSOAFekH55zZocABlHUZg58hi2yUyn6aazg%3D%3D; _fs_sample_user=false; _gid=GA1.2.316147739.1710762606; ihr-cart=init_ctc%3DGR; _d=Gzd5cs3H0UK2DClOCGPXw; ihr-account=sZOuI5a%2B302V9kmvkt577SQns9MBslYem4ZHOtDAG2RoJI8i5YmYQWuGI85rMO2iqiy%2BXgD%2FGCNZDtDua6p%2B9A%3D%3D; ihr-wel=aWhlcmIubWFyY2gyNEBnbWFpbC5jb20%3D; ihr-cln2=CfDJ8Owlin-Q8tFJji2GlTfs7_nIwv4e2uHJs5W6RgD2Us3NTiRaxavYFafuUeBQVFUG7TMO-UDrmLZMT9VWja1hTBcFO4AwmE8vw4iKx9T1oPvoepWpMeDmijmE1c_VW-W7mhUdX7Ixiinl-b_kt7Zu8nFfWOdqpX3ezRVdtnxHsqis5Pq3kkVMzJBZVhumJ8nKdPs8yvBR66U2MU07_Q9bvEDlsiAob2XJkY9tI3NCOymN; last_li_ts=1710767380607; ihr-sc=e60739b105ee9a40decc63994529eb0d12632ef782ef29c405dd6352778983e1; ihr-ocid1=59a5a8c8-065e-4e56-a2dc-1a5c418b3f19; ih-search-hist-1=W3siayI6Im1hZGVjYXNzb3NpZGUiLCJ0IjowfSx7ImsiOiJtYWRlY2Fzc29zaWRlIiwidCI6MH0seyJrIjoiYSdwaWV1IG1hZGVjYXNzb3NpZGUiLCJ0IjowfSx7ImsiOiJuaWFjaW5hbWlkZSBjZW50ZWxsYSIsInQiOjB9LHsiayI6InJvc2VoaXAgb2lsIiwidCI6MH0seyJrIjoiY2VudGVsbGEiLCJ0IjowfSx7ImsiOiJoLXNjYXJzIiwidCI6MH0seyJrIjoibXVyYWQiLCJ0IjowfSx7ImsiOiJuaWFjaW5hbWlkZSIsInQiOjB9LHsiayI6Ik1hZGVjYXNzb3NpZGUgJiBBbGxhbnRvaW4iLCJ0IjowfV0=; ihr-session-id1=aid=59a5a8c8-065e-4e56-a2dc-1a5c418b3f19&rwcd=IGC3335&sc=e60739b105ee9a40decc63994529eb0d12632ef782ef29c405dd6352778983e1; rskxRunCookie=0; rCookie=05pkq6j6tnua2f2orbt50moltx17j39; iher-pref1=bi=0&ifv=1&ihr-pcfg=N&ihr-pcode1=NEW20&lan=en-US&sccode=GR&scurcode=EUR&storeid=0&wp=2; lastRskxRun=1710771645017; __cf_bm=3is0xqMHZHNudjIympdMlyl52_awX.2zCK4tjeYphBI-1710830506-1.0.1.1-lJ__k01wyq2PdayHkCNh2CQr7T2pXS1p3YfhYF3NYfAtUliTe6P9cy5laeRLnzuItQdfJX2GHPYQE.H3hHAfp2jcrd5y4V5uayGrqV_Yb2E; ihr-temse=expires=19%20Mar%202024%2008%3A00%3A5Z; __cfruid=e52af8325653e3c4f9421986b19c6739a6b8a024-1710831635; TAsessionID=2dc7ead4-d523-4724-ac39-4e5a4ab70a01|EXISTING; _clck=18bytmb%7C2%7Cfk7%7C0%7C1519; _pxhd=zg2rEjW6LmmI5XlSHpHxIzeIeY6WC3AuPGUDiktlqoujqVncGI4z6wFlS5Ocs870HL33JHLAVD0iwi/fgd50RA==:MDZwnNQcvKUrM9-yDTsh/kenUi4ZqAOtrNa1-JtKDfq5eLLcHlx1rY2wxEnAr5bNhecnpPydVSoxJ0xDGdp58-XTuzYkfPq3ClC8PiGa88M=; __eoi=ID=7ba9c1626c1172b7:T=1710831736:RT=1710831736:S=AA-AfjaCFNJ-cNyaabcuGHk5hP_c; user-related={"HasNavigatedSite":{"timestamp":1710831774464},"HasEverLoggedIn":true}; _clsk=1swb8t%7C1710831843630%7C10%7C1%7Cb.clarity.ms%2Fcollect; FPGSID=1.1710831634.1710831938.G-SW3NJP516F.Z4FRQ_wKcCkbC1D_rDldnQ; _ga=GA1.2.396423792.1709123512; _scid_r=aed9a9eb-0ec4-48e6-84c6-4d16affd7e56; _rdt_uuid=1709123511601.90f8a0ad-a941-4358-9742-b423c3bf30ac; IR_19332=1710831938723%7C4362503%7C1710831938723%7C%7C; IR_PI=5a191d0d-d635-11ee-ae17-6b60e9215a60%7C1710918338723; _uetsid=a99d15e0e51d11eeb69e6db8f27f0ae0; _uetvid=5942a930d63511ee9f5da9f4c6109222; _ga_SW3NJP516F=GS1.1.1710831633.4.1.1710831939.0.0.0; _px3=84049c296b74b2f3b60d066a602325acb54b64fd764708e1cc92c56488d72496:QQ9iJKcaQKQIWM1q7tT/8Gl6RHrdydWs8yySWfz+Ee5cXkeT5UajBuW06B5KLhHByTHo8o8Er3SSgJti6ukckg==:1000:agG/ChgQPkkwt8oKgE2oNyUA4wvOdtL7h6/qvYnJEi3pj6YNAJ0wYZlJev+H3oNwwImhEZX/x0m1y5UNVAv11JAaIJ/Rvwn6zdze+gAOHsywIjrDIGtgzpM6ocpZBcEQY2GTgpxouKtOHZqYyM5EbgCsQWg6NAU8hKKoktr1SIyASj9tscGxyWOT14O6BPoPWFhvX8h1XwnMAYM5BNUIzrqv1I53MrWO30z0XVs+1Ss=; .iHerbAuth.Cookies=CfDJ8Owlin-Q8tFJji2GlTfs7_mrlNmzeR2PESx8Mr4v2QF3vpjQqYE1NdE1MK9EESduRCkn54xf3sPyL9_52ToKWQAVlXfaT6wbRUdLe8z6QGGUjGuqLFEdJpzZe5uY2-DCQFflYaVAo_85-97ZvUaxp3H2tnDUehPzbwVchjXz8xMF2xqXUUECFNWVnsoB2UXRBS8kL-ewEnVThkO16_BRjZXGYVrMV0ASoX5zi7pO-BKF-HpYY7BB9PTRrAB85aX-gVgJuC87MSUfbxaEdiHgdSA6gAgn_Mzcz-Wq_L8cou_VcylZZFs_Jys-JoBGCZYIC3rGXFaLDz22iOa8hBUD6117jILisxBO9Llz2D8rxDMNOFEicJjJ7PMeXrvvawSr0UV7NIdHCr4DUs4liN-MkM-_p9I65HOakEfA5toBhJLsXqZhtltdLG_0Iph_WPhvFFPfnN5Gi_xMPPWow8sogy5jcoRnMlHhDykXv1TIaJhTQFDtSvwpNJMvvAPKYJQMKoLuBqF7vXv0ZzTyowAv7fdI2GLC950vbOXC5FVmYsl3Tg5vkuGDe8gPEVrrwH9xFHjWITgv3INq0MejGX3sRUBwMeM2FBP4mnvSnrfuXR28UesDx9b1DI6kdsuzvD0ePhWBt9lXonLQi7qrMhegCdWbBEGp5KnAGUFUobUseTFH0HX7P1VpHCFJkwWB-4Sd1YkyM7Own2hNJJ_eItsgBGxlhDBQDMnC73IjNkhjaNosoHxtMz1EOqzDE-hv4BJCg2Hnn9sQN5c24j0uhMGJMTn_RYo1rGE5b9cTR0Ef31O7uS7by_arR6dXofrBl53qphCUskDsKDZQyM0rESvL7akeEjSx8AVUl4hPcsOZLlt-XBEuaQ9pjT4KUkursloDrctQ0C2F25fI8ifk0aR2e8zBSG-9d39ZgW4X6567V0z39CnzWqTB0AAsDixSCmHWBCV-7obd6X_I-gLfQFVmJVpv3XWcCWv2o36yqrJkpk6UFQfFKBGNf_F22DDobvxnMN5MMnwHKTZq_MNUv8gjEqfOAo0o0J9Y0Pu-i1TnfqIYB5A4fka-9iydALcVKD1SZcr5PYqwI70iJmRzZdImHquhAzzxhB1Zr26sBjVbSuE0BLLRsISuceV7yEtOEkG0j7Ie7ye8zo9d9Cb-LtAFdi97yST7Ru6-i7_3IqCb4dYiTwHtq6Xzw2W5L-6GEbAhxsF5NzmSJpF0LBB__JL0DqVpSbXhJckBirJWL9JmVeTIOsyEfWSZK9bAggPVZiA4TGhY8FoFR8CiWUSHx1uOfM2h37XNZuEwwyPJX_Sg6btcDtMQpXzBowW7_7otDe1_JILqHdugZC7bGfdXKY7EcoQEhGtRZaI7Hb_9AHZpzIB2Cm2aR_j-QSzTsKJXfDWGTo6xSpLwZGew1FB2pypBF-oFG5bXBaW6Cn16fx-NjrW70m3elLtsX8TeiI8Kk098O2L8GDPJxNdIco8HJESnyvJ0IuFQd_IpZ5uI_w6D_8L8nH4jEsNlRsFC743roKLwSVGEsXxl8cOHGxMWoxZ9srbhkBRZJv7Kte4hbF0KjFmLmjMJH2LKDb98YTpVHVAWIEudvqJu218U6rYzymk4AJlxReowCddhGmhb9iTK_4n9NpQ7FSPzpDD7ldxHvDAxIK3k6UVquYKyy_2tDjSaAuuJYKiOyW59QEGeXR_vgnYnjXgHKPDPUxGICLfN5qCSLgGKkhp2faP27VfsqVeiIuCnjWbEvhRjYAmj0FbMnb0D74ypQoNLGOwnykXDrQHo6cDFncq_vZw-pWjJk5LTqvqJI9So3T3LWZyy7wzU2h_nge2xwqeJX7NmXwPiWgWRUMWtJqqDwv8LlBrESPf43xwBWRfUfmTzi_iVpjHmuiiFjYVI7F8Pq1PsU-sB0TVK3NEpuoH3GMekAArAFhTNhhtYfkJAGUM1AEbk6qEyd9iAVYa6UDMoPXfs-JyHM1EIf_EnqtBzJRyoNBmhHOJsiLJIgByWmUSa68xQHGvVDKhqNtDqlS0u_qB2MYlFIGkCQn258897bYeqrHBoSQrMbRBARWCVuiCnUehn-lpwgYoQJe6X5dgs-aDGyqs7_qmNS0AVGK_P2ACmcGBuhUN0QKTIiZGabIyTu4KRRIkHnaTX97R7ANTFMR3nKBbDG9LlThA6_ZFTqMvbfzf7r7d4DYbMnAr5B_iwUv_71X3zXKrD-9dx55V_C-6X3sC84yxmk1esVF5vvtATYCmSQK8c3At-JfTWq2gZz9s0zNApH7uaRfnveb4HmKH_9egoHDRReXhEOQ21K9reHLSnb7PwB5gcJtFe4TXoSlgRs858EeCb-BqOUTt9rve4pujReJXbvruO2shyap2DAERpiQ_rWdGKSdbNdzcAYIPXfUmveM_S5lsSLyTFMDuv7EGfwsUP60E1iiyqdHbsELXanUOZh4LvgAIVSZ_JOL8FXmdwfJUMDuYpnXINE9KCC2UIdHWOAHSZiShpzKj6KykJY1IDMkfKK4JFWf34ou2kr753M2-8YSSzeacTQ3zH3IFGerooSA',
            'Dnt' : '1',
            'Referer' : 'https://gr.iherb.com/pr/panoxyl-acne-foaming-wash-10-benzoyl-peroxide-maximum-strength-5-5-oz-156-g/103844',
            'Sec-Ch-Ua' : '"Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"',
            'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile' : '?0',
            'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform' : '"Windows"',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest' : 'document',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode' : 'navigate',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site' : 'same-origin',
            'Sec-Fetch-User' : '?1',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1',
            'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

        }
    page = requests.get(link, headers = headers)
    soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")
    # reviewratings = ?
    reviewtitle= soup.find_all('a', class_="css-bvdvm5")
    reviewcontent = soup.find_all('a', class_="css-1so5ywb")
    reviewdate = soup.find_all('span', class_='css-1fktd33')


After inpecting the site for 2 minutes, I noticed that all the review information is in a <script> tag with id = reviews-schema in the <head> tag.
Basically, it's just plain JSON.

So you can use the following:
page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("script", {"id": "reviews-schema"})
reviews_data = json.loads(script.text)

All you have to do is to parse this JSON correctly.

Thank you very much. So then how I extract the 'reviewRating': {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': '5'} ratingValue from each review comment?

@user24008005 Loop through the list review using a for loop.
